# omxplayer - running from command line is much longer than voice's length

Tags: audio, omxplayer

On my Raspberry Pi 3 I got `omxplayer` which I am using to run mp3 file:

`omxplayer -o alsa /home/voice/7.mp3`

With `-i` option I get this output:

```
Input #0, mp3, from '/home/voice/7.mp3':
  Metadata:
    Software        : Lavf55.19.100
  Duration: 00:00:01.57, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 130 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : LAME3.99r
have a nice day ;)
```

Unfortunately executing first command takes about 9 seconds, while my mp3 file is only 2 seconds long. What can I do to get this command running for only 2 seconds too?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to run omxplayer from a `ramdisk`:

```
sudo -s

mkfs -q /dev/ram15 5120
mkdir -p /ramdisk
mount /dev/ram14 /ramdisk
cp /usr/bin/omxplayer /ramdisk
cp /usr/bin/omxplayer.bin /ramdisk
nice -n -19 /ramdisk/omxplayer -o alsa /home/voice/7.mp3
```

It might help in loading time.  However, it might not.  If it does improve loading time, then you could make a script or service file that creates the `ramdisk` with each boot.

However, it's possible that `aplay` will load faster.  So, you may want to transcode the `mp3` as `wav` with ffmpeg on a different machine... since ffmpeg can be difficult to install on a Raspberry Pi.